# Django : how to fix empty slug?

Tags: django

I have a urls :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"admin/"       , admin.site.urls),
    url(r"users/"       , include(("users.urls", "users")     , namespace='users')      ),
    path('bristol/'     , include(('bristol.urls', "bristol") , namespace='bristol')    ),
    url(r""             , include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

But I can't connect to my server if I don't put any end slug to my url :
[image]

What should I change in my url patterns to redirect localhost:8000 directly to the login view ?

I tried :

```
urlpatterns += [ url(r"/"             , reverse("login"))]
```

But It didn't help :-/

**Edit 1 :**

Trying Wilem's solution  worked at last, and the issue was partially due to refresh issues on my browser (see comments):

Comment: Since `django.contrib.auth.urls` does not contain any view with path `/`, it will thus not match with any pattern.

Comment: should I then link an empty string with my reverse function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `django.contrib.auth.urls` does not contain any view with path `/`, it will thus not match with any pattern.

You can define an extra pattern that for example maps on the `LoginView`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'users/', include(('users.urls', 'users'), namespace='users')),
    path('bristol/', include(('bristol.urls', 'bristol'), namespace='bristol')),
    url(r'', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', LoginView.as_view(), name='index')
]
```

But it is rather *odd* to map the index path on the `LoginView`, normally you make a view that acts as some sort of "dashboard". You can make use of the [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) to prevent people from looking at the dashboard if they are not logged in.

Comment: @RomainJouin: you did set the `APPEND_SLASH` setting on `True` right?

Comment: Yes It is set to True

Comment: @RomainJouin: what if you visit `localhost:8000/`?

Comment: @RomainJouin: that's not with a slash, there should be slash after the `:8000`.

Comment: yep, it is removed automatically by django

Comment: @RomainJouin: no, Django can not interact with the browser that way. This is just the browser removing it. You can try the empty string as path, but it is simply bad design that the browser strips this. Normally this should then be handled by Nginx to append a slash. Did you add `CommonMiddleware` to the middleware? Because `APPEND_SLASH` normally should append it back.

Comment: Seems I had indeed a refresh issue with chrome